# Make a line of divs with borders and margins fill the width dynamically

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Consider the following code:

**CSS:**

```css
.output {
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.box{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
.first{
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="line">
    <div class="output">5</div>
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box first"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="box"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="box"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="box"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div class="box last"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the divs to horizontally line up and fill the 'line' div' (the space of the parent), but dynamically e.g. I do not want to specify fixed widths for each of the boxes I just want them to fill up the horizontal space.

Can this be done?

Comment: "I want the divs to horizontally line up..." - are you referring to the `.box` elements, or the `.line` element's direct descendants (`.output` and `.boxes`)? please rephrase your question for clarity.

Comment: output and boxes should sit side by side. Boxes will contain 2 or more 'box' and I want them to horizontally line up alongside output in a line - hope that makes sense

Comment: so the above should look something like | 5 |    |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I really have no idea what you want to do. Can you make it clearer? or may you attach some images, or example?

Comment: I just want everything in the html above to sit on one line horizontally. I cannot specify widths and I need it to be fluid as the number of 'box' is variable. So I cannot for example float output and boxes left and give each box a width of 20% because I may have 100 boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/css-table) way to do this is `display: table`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tPCwD/

Note that you can change the number of `.box` elements and it still works.

```css
.line {
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.output {
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px; /* take the minimum amount of space */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.output > span {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.boxes {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* to force equal width columns */
}
.box {
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
    background: #ccc;
}
.first {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

If support for IE7 and lower is required, you could use JavaScript for only those browsers (conditional comment). There's a [`.htc` JavaScript polyfill available](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/), but I'm not sure how well it would work with this layout. Alternatively, you could just use a real `<table>`.

Comment: NOOO! Not tables for layout! ;-)

Comment: excellent answer this is exactly what I wanted thank you! I have one last small problem, I need to wrap each div in an anchor tag to make it clickable, however when I do this it breaks the width of that div, is there any way I can make those divs clickable?

Comment: You're welcome. The fastest fix for that is to change the `div` elements to `a` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tPCwD/1/.

Comment: Hi, I will definitely accept it, just trying to get it working on my code. Is there any reason why wrapping an anchor around the div makes it not inherit the width?

Comment: Its ok I got it working, just misspelt something. Thanks a lot for your help the jsFiddle example works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `output` and `boxes` to fill the horizontal space, I'd use `float:left` on `output`. That way it will take up as much space as in needs and the `boxes` box will fill the rest of the space.

If, on the other hand, you want to have the five `box` `div`s to fill their parent, just give each one a `width:20%` and set `box-sizing:border-box` to take account for the borders. In this case, you do have to give the browser some idea of how big each box should be in relation to each other, otherwise how would it know which box to expand to fill the space?

Another alternative for the 5 `box`es, if you want to be on the 'cutting edge' is to look into  the [flexbox specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_flexbox).

Comment: Hi gareth, I can't do width 20% because the number of boxes I may have can vary from 2 to 100, sorry I should have mentioned this in the question. When I float them left, I always get extra space on the right which they do not fill

Comment: In that case flexbox sounds like just what you need. Unfortunately, it's experimental at the moment so it won't work in IE or Opera, and according to [this page](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) Firefox and Safari only have partial support at the moment.

Comment: I also want it to be widely supported, not CSS3 or HTML5, thanks!

Comment: @sam: Do you need IE7 support?